Django-Celery with Docker-Compose Gives Error: "celery": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
I have a docker compose file used to work, but in the last couple days I started to see
executable file not found in $PATH: unknown kind of error but not sure where could go wrong.
This is in windows environment, using Rancher Desktop as the docker client.
The docker compose file is basically starting a local server of Django. There are in total 3 containers: Django web app, rabbitmq, and celery worker.
version: '3.9'

services:
  # drf container
  gunicorn-drf: &drf
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /workspace/drf
    command: gunicorn --workers 4 --threads 2 drf.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - SOME_ENV_VAR=${ENV_VAR}
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - celery_worker

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    image: rabbitmq:3.12-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"

  celery_worker:
    <<: *drf
    working_dir: /workspace/drf
    command: celery -A drf worker -P threads --concurrency=3 --loglevel=info
    ports: []
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

And this is the Docker file the Django depends on
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFED 1
RUN mkdir /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . /workspace/

# install dependencies of the project
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

I am seeing this error message:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create 
failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "celery": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

If anyone can suggest couple possible causes of this issue would be fantastic. Many thanks!

Does your requirements.txt file in fact include a Celery dependency?  You should be able to run things like docker compose run celery_worker pip list to see what Python packages are installed in the container.
